# Azure API Management oAuth 2.0 Security

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I am trying to implement oAuth 2.0 security for my API in Azure. I have configured the authorization and token endpoints to point to my portal etc and the server is created ok.

When using the API to test a call and set the Authentication type to "Authorization Code" the login screen on my portal correctly appears and I can enter my credentials.

However when I then press ok to validate me I get an exception from the my portal indicating that the Authorization Request is null.

If I use SoapUI to test it all works fine, as Azure is no involved.

This is my first attempt at setting one of these up.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to discussion on MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/552b1442-0fd3-41ac-9f2c-4e84a365f364/oauth-20-not-passing-oauth-header?forum=azureapimgmt